# How do I only print out the last two digits of a hexadecimal number

Tags: c

So if the number is converted as ffffff9b i just want it to print the 9b. So if a is the variable.
printf("number= %x\n",a);

Comment: try: `printf("%x\n", a & 0xff)`

Comment: Thanks that worked. My first post here so unsure of how to post. thank you

Comment: The problem is you want to use `unsigned char` instead of `char`!

Answer (score 4):

You can always mask the bits you don't want.

```
unsigned num =  0xffffff9b;
unsigned mask = 0x000000ff; 
printf("number= %x\n", (num&mask));
```

`0xff` works too, but since we're dealing with bits I prefer to show them all - but that is a personal choice ;-)

This sets each bit you do want to 1 - so when you do the and the result will have a 1 where the original has a 1. Every other bit is 0 so when you do the and they will all end up as 0.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Very good point - Always unsigned for bit masks. Don't know what I was thinking!

Answer (score 2):

What do you want displayed as the last two digits of `B0AD007`? 
If you’re happy with `7`, then use

```c
printf("number= %x\n", a & 0xff);
```

as stated in [kaylum’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63984264/3960947#comment113143763_63984264) and [John3136’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63984264/3960947#63984296). 
But, if you want `07`, then use

```c
printf("number= %02x\n", a & 0xff);
```

or

```c
printf("number= %2.2x\n", a & 0xff);
```